# I can't use the custom class after importing the jar file into the eclipse project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar

I made a custom class. I wrote the class code and put it into mycustomclass.class.  I put the .class file into a Winrar archive and then renamed the archive to mycustomclass.jar.

this is the code i am just testing out to see how importing custom classes work.

```
public class mycustomclass {

int weight;
int height;

public int calculatebmi(int weight, int height){

int bmi = ((weight+height)*(weight+height))/(height*height);
return bmi;

}
}
```

the file structure is like this for this jar file:

`mycustomclass.jar>mycustomclass.class(inside the jar file)`

I then added the jar file into the project by clicking on the "add external jar file" under java build path. I also checked the checkbox next to the jar file name in the `order and export` list of the java build path properites.  When I goto add the class to the mainactivity.java file like this:

`import mycustomclass;`

it says `mycustomclass cannot be resolved`

the jar file is under the referenced libraries folder and the mycustomclass.class file is under the "default package" like this:

`Refereneced Libraries>default package>mycustomclass.class`

I thought the custom class file has to be in a package heierarchy so I created a folder in the jar file called mycustomclassfolder and put the mycustomclass.class file in there.

`mycustomclass.jar>mycustomclassfolder>mycustomclass.class`

I then did this.

`import mycustomclassfolder.mycustomclass;`

error message:

`mycustomclassfolder.mycustomclass cannot be resolved`

this is how it is listed in the project files list:

`mycustomclass.jar>mycustomclassfolder>mycustomclass.class`

What do I have to do in addition to importing the files into the project so I can use the class in to the mainactivity.java file with `import ...` keyword?

thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if winrar can produce a valid `.jar` file (jar is essentially a `.zip`, not a `.rar`). Try the [jar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jar.html) tool.

Comment: I used the tool to make the jar and after adding the jar file into the project i still get same error message: `mycustomclass cannot be resolved to a type`. what do I have to do in order to make this work? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

2 issues:

1. You should use `jar` tool shipping with your JDK to create the jar file. Compressed file generated by any other tool may not be compatible with jar file format.
2. You cannot `import` a file in default package. It is not even necessary to import the class in default package. Just use the class after adding the jar file containing the class to the classpath/build classpath.

Comment: Hi.  I was able to create the jar file using the jar tool. but it is still telling me the same error: `mycustomclass cannot be resolved to a type` with `import mycustomclass;`. where is the `classpath/build classpath` property that I can set? So I don't even have to import the jar file into the project to do that? what if I have folders in the jar file and class files within those folders? If that is the case, do I have to import the jar file and then access the classes with the import keyword? thanks.